# mysql query using 4 tables to produce small report

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting a query to work.  4 tables are used in this query.  I want a report looking like this...

`Name   Success Failure
jdn     5       1
wer     0       3`

I want to produce data for the last 24 hours. Here is a sample query I tried and didn't work.

```
select r.name as jid,
 i.id as theid,
 (select sum(counter) as scount 
  from WebServicesIfSummarySuccess 
  where id=theid 
    and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now() 
    and sum(counter) >0 and sum(counter) is not null 
  group by id
 ) as success,
 (select sum(counter) as fcount 
  from WebServicesIfSummaryFailure 
  where id=theid 
    and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now() 
    and sum(counter) >0 and sum(counter) is not null 
  group by id
 ) as failure
 from router r, interface i 
 where r.rid = i.rid  
 and r.name like '%wi%' ;
```

Here are the table layouts.

`router
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rid   | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(120)           | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| pop   | char(10)            | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| popid | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
interface
+-------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | char(255)                 | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| rid         | int(11)                   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| speed       | bigint(11)                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | char(255)                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | enum('active','inactive') | YES  |     | active  |                |
+-------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
Failure and Success are 2 separate tables
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dtime   | datetime         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| counter | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rate    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

Comment: Don't you have any error when you run the query?

Comment: I've had several different ones as I have tried many ways.  The last message I got was ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: I tried you suggestion.  I changed theid to i.id and still getting the same error.  ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.   I find that strange since I'm not using group function.  Maybe I should be? somewhere?

Comment: Note that you cannot use `SUM()` in your `WHERE` clause. You should add a `HAVING` clause and place it there.

Comment: @Uri Hartmann is right. You can just delete "and sum(counter) >0 and sum(counter) is not null ".

Comment: When  switched to having I got ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dtime' in 'having clause'.  How would I use dtime to select a time period?

Comment: deleteing the sum(counter)  returns data but not what I need.  Its not grouping and I get nulls when there is no data.  Do I need to put grouping at the end of the primary query?

Comment: the group by r.name at the end gave me the list I want.  I just need to get rid of the nulls now.  Where can I do that?

Comment: At the end of your query by writing having success >0 and success is not null and fail >0 and fail is not null

Comment: This is what I use to pull from success or failure.  It does what I want.  I need to combine them somehow and so far I have not been successful.`select r.name,i.id,t.dtime,sum(t.counter) as counter from router r, interface i, Success t where r.rid=i.rid and i.id=t.id and r.name like '%wi%' and t.dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now() group by r.name`

Comment: You can use join to combine them.

Comment: @ahmet  Here is the query that I have so far..`select r.name as jid, i.id as theid,  (select sum(counter) as scount from Success where id=theid and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now()) as success,  (select sum(counter) as fcount from Failure where id=theid and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now()) as fail from router r, interface i where r.rid = i.rid  and r.name like '%wji%'  group by r.name;`

Comment: I get `name id NULL 3` or `name id NULL NULL`  I'm getting close.

Comment: Did you try this :    select r.name as jid, i.id as theid, (select sum(counter) as scount from Success where id=theid and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now()) as success, (select sum(counter) as fcount from Failure where id=theid and dtime between date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) and now()) as fail from router r, interface i where r.rid = i.rid and r.name like '%wji%' group by r.name  having success >0 and success is not null and fail >0 and fail is not null

Comment: I'm working on the join of 2 selects.  so far its not working.  There could be a fail without success so I don't see those records in the join.  Still working on it.

Comment: @ahmet  The query output looks correct.  I'm going to audit the output and study on how it works.  I'll post back after I audit.

Comment: I found a problem.  The count isn't summing correctly.  Also missing some cases of 0 fail 1 success or 1 fail 0 success.  I have a solution for that.  I need fail+success >0.  I'm trying to join the two queries I mentioned above.

Comment: You should give an example like I have these values in my table and I want to see these results in my table and I tried this query (as you did). Then, everyone can answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I  understand your message.  Due to time constraints I had to come up with a different solution involving perl   I'll still keep trying to make this work.  Thank you for your help @ahmet   I really appreciate it.